# Babel equivalent for other modes

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Babel lets you include code blocks of different programming languages inside an Org-mode document, which can be printed and executed. Is there something similar for other modes as well?
For example, I would like to include code blocks inside TeX-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do is write your document in org mode, and then export
it to LaTeX (`M-x org-export-dispatch` and then `l` `l`).

If you're looking for other options: some languages provide their own tools to
export literate programs to LaTeX. For example:

- Racket has [Scribble](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/) which can generate LaTeX
- R has [Sweave](https://bookdown.org/kochiuyu/Technical-Analysis-with-R/sweave-r-code-in-latex.html) which can generate LaTeX

But those are obviously language-specific. As far as I know, org-mode and
org-babel is the most general solution for this sort of thing.

If you really want to *write* in LaTeX rather than in org-mode, some things you
can try:

- Some LaTeX packages have been created to invoke specific programs from
  LaTeX. For example, the `gnuplottex` package allows you to specify `gnuplot`
  source in your LaTeX file, and it will automatically run the `gnuplot` code,
  generate a graph, and then include the graph in your document.
- Otherwise, you can create a simple build pipeline (what some web devs could
  call an "asset pipeline") that runs your code, creates output files (say,
  `txt` files), and then in your LaTeX you can `\include` those output files.
  You could do this with, say, a `Makefile`.

Comment: I just saw another question with an awesome answer which, in retrospect, is probably closer to what you were asking: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62286/library-for-code-execution-for-markdown-via-org-babel